# Replacing a particular line in a .inc file using golang

Tags: regex, string, file, replace, go

I have a file named aab.inc and i have a line **$VP_Name="Some Messages"** I wrote a code in golang so that it reads the file aab.inc and Removes **any line** that has a **word** **VP_Name** and in my code i also included that That line(which contains the word **VP_Name**) is replaced with **$VP_Name="Alternate Message"** but my problem is it never deletes the line if i give the word as **$VP_Name** and it replaces the line as **="Alternate Message"** in the place if I give the replacing word as **$VP_Name="Alternate Message"**  . But it deletes the line if give the word as **VP_Name** alone(Without $) and replaces the line as **VP_Name="Alternate Message"** if the replacing text is given without the $ symbol.

My code is as follows

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"
import "os"
import "io/ioutil"
func main() {

    ConfigFile1, err := os.Open("aab.inc")
         if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
                 return
         }
        defer ConfigFile1.Close()

    ConfigFiledata1, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(ConfigFile1)
    //Try with $VP_Name
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?m)[\r\n]+^.*VP_Name.*$")
    // Actual Word is $VP_Name="Alternate Message" 
    res := re.ReplaceAllString(string(ConfigFiledata1), "\nVP_Name=\"Alternate Message\"")

    fmt.Println(res)    

    out := []byte(res)
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("aab_final.inc",out, 0666); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
}
```

The new replaced line should come in the next line should not append with any other lines but even i use \n before the replacing text the result is as below

Output

```
$VP_Roll="";VP_Name="Alternate Message";
$VP_Failure="Yes";
```

What is the Problem in including the $ in the code and why the text is not replaced in a new line even \n was specified.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, when your regexp becomes `""(?m)[\r\n]+^.*$VP_Name.*$"`, the regexp engine tries to find the end of the string (`$`) right before the text "VP_Name", so what did you expect?

Comment: So how could i find a character $

Comment: By escaping it with a backslash. You really should start with some introductory material on using regular expressions. [here](http://play.golang.org/p/BArHfpBPiM)'s how I would do what you need. To expand on this solution a bit more: there's no need to explicitly mess wiwith line endings as you are slurping the whole file and process it in a single piece.

Comment: Thank you so much now it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped. But please don't just blindly copy my solution! You have to work out several things from it for yourself: 1) Escaping; 2) Capturing groups of characters with `(...)`; 3) Exclusion matchng (`[^"]*` matches 0 or more of any characters except `"`); 4) Using of captured groups in the substitution text (read the manual on `Regexp.ReplaceAllString()`).